# Huge Apple Mail Logs (Connection Logging Enabled)

Tags: macos, mail.app

I was doing some routine cleanup of my HDD, when I noticed some huge log files in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Logs/Mail`.

Where do I toggle those log files off and on?

Comment: OMFG, 360gb of logs ! I got a new mac now, thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the `Window` menu, there is the `Connection Doctor`, which has a checkbox, showing the toggle to enable / disable logging.

[image: Connection Doctor]

You can also see at a glance in the menubar of the main Mail window, if it is enabled:

[image: menubar]

Comment: My mac showed over 150GB in "System Storage" and it was all grayed out so you could not clean it up from the Manage Storage screen. I deleted these log files and my System Storage went down to practically nothing. So if you are wondering what is taking up so much room in System Storage, its could easily be these logs.