# macOS installations shows less space than I have

Tags: macos, install, disk-space

I cleared my system to install the BigSur beta:
[image]

So I have **62 GB** free space.

But when Im in the installation process its shows the following:

[image]

Just **28 GB** free space. How can I fix this?

when I look up my HDD via finder it shows me:

[image]

**So that 34 GB should be purgable. But how to delete this stuff since my recycling bin is empty.**

Comment: As this is a beta, you should report the issue to Apple.

Comment: Its not a beta since im on catalina and was trying to install big sur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:
I just created a new APFS parition and reserved as much space as possible. Then the space which was shown as purgeable was deleted automatically. After that i removed the partition again and had all the free space.

Comment: This would be super useful if you put in a screen shot or command how to do this, I think we’ll need quite a few threads like this to help everyone that’s not seeing APFS containers and purgeable space as something that can be managed / cajoled when needed rather than just letting the system prune things when storage pressure time arrives later. +1 even without extra details or an edit.

Comment: Works perfectly in MacOS Catalina :-D. If anyone is interested here's a step by step tutorial: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/disk-utility/dskua9e6a110/mac

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your startup drives... Just boot into Recovery Mode and run First Aid.

NOTE: First Aid will temporarily lock the startup volume.

Comment: This I also tired but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Time machine local snapshots have been known to take up lots of purgeable disk space. Try entering this in Terminal.app

```
tmutil listlocalsnapshots /
```

if you see a list of things printed, those are likely using up your space. They are programmed to remove themsleves as your space fills up. Here is a [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340905/how-to-delete-all-local-timemachine-snapshots) with more info on this topic.

If you just want to remove them, you can run this command

```
for d in $(tmutil listlocalsnapshotdates | grep "-"); do sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots $d; done
```

and then after a few seconds go over to Disk Utility.